# iteration of a function over complex 2d matrix with np and cm

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to iterate over a 2D Matrix with a fct ?

In Pseudocode it should look like this:

```
import cmath as cm
matrixphase = 0
complexmatrix = fouriertransformation of an image

for each entry:
    matrixphase[i,j]= cm.phase(complexmatrix[i,j])
print(matrix phase)
```

I think there is a really simple solution to this problem, but I just don't know the way to it yet.

Comment: You may be right, it might be easy. But you didn't really give us much to go on. Show us the code you have written so far, even if currently it is "wrong". https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok, i did find a very easy way. If theres nothing more elegant in python, theres still the possibility to run a simple for-case:
In my case like this:

`for i in range(len(source)):

            for j in range(len(source[i])):`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem didn't mention a list-of-lists named `source`,
but imagine that we had one.
Then a C programmer would probably use nested `i`, `j` `for` loops,
while a pythonista would tend to favor [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, row in enumerate(source):
    for j, item in enumerate(row):
        ...
```

If you're displaying items, or computing a simple sum,
so the indices are not needed,
then this would suffice:

```
for row in source:
    for item in row:
        ...
```